# Delete an element from a list C++

Tags: c++, list, erase

I have a problem, I'm trying to delete an element in a string list but it doesn't work for the last position. I would also like to display the position of the iterator with an arithmetic operation.

list l = {"a","b","c", "d"};

```
for(std::list<string>::iterator it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); it++)

    cout << " &l["<< it - l.begin() <<"]: "  << &*it << "  l["<< it - l.begin() <<"]: " <<  *it << endl;
    cout << endl;

for(std::list<string>::iterator itt = l.begin(); itt != l.end(); itt++){

    if(*itt == "d")  itt = l.erase(itt);
    cout << " &l["<< itt - l.begin() <<"]: "  << &*itt << "  l["<< itt - l.begin() <<"]: " <<  *itt << endl;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: a list iterator loses it validity after it is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It "doesn't work" because this line will cause `itt` to become the `end()` iterator when erasing the last element:

```
if(*itt == "d")  itt = l.erase(itt);
```

Then the `for` loop does `itt++` before the loop condition check, and incrementing the `end()` iterator is undefined behavior.

You need to modify your loop like this:

```
for (std::list<string>::iterator itt = l.begin(); itt != l.end(); /* */) {
    if (*itt == "d") {
        itt = l.erase(itt);
    } else {
        ++itt;
    }

    // You cannot safely access *itt here because it might be l.end()
}
```

Comment: thk, but the elemnt "d" is not delete, it display : l[0]:b l[1]:c  l[2]:d l[3]:a

Comment: @mamaka How are you displaying that text? Is it from the loop *before* you erase the "d" element?

Answer (score 1):

Two issues. First:

```
it - l.begin()
```

List iterators aren't random access, so they don't have `operator-()` defined for the obvious reason that that would be an expensive operation. If you want to do that, you have to do:

```
std::distance(l.begin(), it);
```

Second, the line:

```
itt = l.erase(itt);
```

for the last element will cause `itt` to become `l.end()`, so the subsequent `itt++` is undefined behavior. What you will have to do instead is conditionally increment the iterator:

```
for (std::list<string>::iterator itt = l.begin(); itt != l.end(); /* nothing */) {
    if (*itt == "d") {
        itt = l.erase(itt);
    }
    else {
        // cout stuff here
        ++itt;
    }
}
```